# How to send data object which contain upload files and string to controller using ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am sending array of object which contain upload file data and some string values to my controller using ajax but it sending failed.

I also tried with formdata but no luck.I want to know how i send data to controller.

Jquery/View Code:

```
function SaveBrandDetail() {
    debugger;
    var data = new Array();
    var tablecount = 0;        
    $(".DataRow").each(function () {
        tablecount = tablecount + 1;
        var row = {
            "SaleStartDateString": $(this).find(".clsSaleStartDateForVal").val(),
            "BrandDetailId": $(this).find(".clsBrandDetailId").val(),
            "SaleExpiryDateString": $(this).find(".clsSaleEndDateForVal").val(),
            "BrandId": $(this).find(".clsBrandId").val(),
            "Amount": $(this).find(".clsAmount").val(),
            "CategoryId": $(this).find(".clsSubCategoryId").val(),
            "ParentCategoryId": $(this).find(".clsParentCategoryId").val(),
            "fileUpload": $(this).find(".fileUploadData").get(0).files[0]

        };

        data.push(row);
    });    

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveData","Data")',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json;',
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             success: function (msg) {

             },
             error: function () {

             }
         });


}
```

Controller File:

```
 public ActionResult SaveData(List<Data> data)
 {

        bool saved = false;
  }
```

i expect to recieve data with upload file in my controller.i have declared HttpPostedFileBase in my modal class.

Comment: You need to use FormData for file upload.

Comment: i used but it was given error can you modify my code for form data? @vinothkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 $(".DataRow").each(function () {
        tablecount = tablecount + 1;
        var row = {
            "SaleStartDateString": $(this).find(".clsSaleStartDateForVal").val(),
            "BrandDetailId": $(this).find(".clsBrandDetailId").val(),
            "SaleExpiryDateString": $(this).find(".clsSaleEndDateForVal").val(),
            "BrandId": $(this).find(".clsBrandId").val(),
            "Amount": $(this).find(".clsAmount").val(),
            "CategoryId": $(this).find(".clsSubCategoryId").val(),
            "ParentCategoryId": $(this).find(".clsParentCategoryId").val(),
            "FileName": $(this).find(".fileUploadData").get(0).files[0].name
        };
        var file = $(this).find(".fileUploadData").get(0).files[0];
        formData.append(file.name, file);
        data.push(row);
    });    
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveData","Data")',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: formdata,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: function (msg) {

             },
             error: function () {

             }
         });


public ActionResult SaveData(string data)
 {
    var files = Request.Files;
    List<Data> d = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Data>>(data);
    foreach(var item in d)
    {
      var file = files[item.FileName];
    }
        bool saved = false;
  }
```

Comment: what to send in ajax data object?

Comment: how i know which file is for which record?@uxmaan ali

Comment: i added file name to send files. you can set BrandDetailId or something you want to set. I does not mean that files are not retrieved on the server end

Comment: You can send file.name in the data object while pushing row to data array. And on the server you can get by Request.Files["name"]

Comment: Request.Files always get null in controller.

Comment: did you add in the ajax processData: false,contentType: false, ?

Comment: I edit the answer kindly check now. It should work perfect.

Comment: its working with very little change in code..  formData.append(file, file.name); swap name with file... @Uxmaan Ali thanx